# Can we say the human race won The Great War in No Game No Life: Zero or Tet won?

Tags: no-game-no-life

In the movie, the human race really tried so hard so that they can win the war but in the final moment, Riku finally summon the Star Cup but unfortunately his both arm were blast off... and then Tet finally show up and give a hand to Riku.

After that, Tet use his power to repair the whole world and made the world calm down for awhile. So basically it was Tet power that made the world peace for awhile but isn't the human race actually contribute more than Tet right?

If Riku didn't plan this, Tet wouldn't come out and help the human race right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main aim of Riku was to end the Great War so that they can live in peace. So basically the win condition is achieved at the end of the movie. Thus we can say that the human race won the war because:

- Peace achieved.
- Human race recognized (as exceed) and given the name Imanity by Tet.

*Bonus:*

There is a very hot debate about how Riku died and it's not %100 clear. Some even say "Riku actually become Deus before dying and created Tet unconsciously". However, it's pretty obvious that Riku didn't plan anything related to Tet. That's is why there is no clear answer to the question "who".